# SQL - Comparing and Grouping Data on multiple rows

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query my database to find which products sold less in October than in either November or December.

I thought something like below would do it but I have a feeling the sub query will be returning the mininimum quantity for the whole database rather than for the specific product.

There must be some way of doing this using GROUP BY but I cant figure it out.

```
SELECT Category, Product 
  FROM Sales 
 WHERE SaleQuantity < (SELECT MIN(SaleQuantity) 
                       FROM Sales 
                       WHERE MonthNumber > 10) 
   AND MonthNumber = 10
```

Data looks like:

```
Category   Product     MonthNumber   SaleQuantity
---------- ----------- ------------- -----------
11         14          10            210
11         14          11            200
11         14          12            390
15         12          10            55
15         12          11            24
17         12          12            129
19         10          10            12
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Have you considered a CTE with product, month and min(sales) and then joining on that?

Comment: I just thought there might be a simple way of getting this data using standard SQL

Comment: It's all a matter of taste, but my experience with a query as you give in your question is that you get a simple, clean implementation if you use a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT Category,
         Product, 
         SUM( s.SaleQuantity ) AS saleOcotber,
         SUM( ISNULL( son.SaleQuantity, 0 ) ) AS saleNovember,
         SUM( ISNULL( sod.SaleQuantity, 0 ) ) AS saleDecember
FROM Sales s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales son ON son.Category = s.Category
     AND son.Product = s.Product
     AND son.MonthNumber = 11
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales sod ON sod.Category = s.Category
     AND sod.Product = s.Product
     AND sod.MonthNumber = 11
WHERE s.MonthNumber = 10
GROUP BY Category,Product
WHERE SUM( s.SaleQuantity ) < SUM( ISNULL( son.SaleQuantity, 0 ) )
   OR SUM( s.SaleQuantity ) < SUM( ISNULL( sod.SaleQuantity, 0 ) )
```

I have no tested this select but i think it will do the job if there is something not clear
please ask

Best Regards,
Iordan

PS. I presume you are using some version of MSSQL if not try to rewrite it by yourself int SQL you are using

Answer (score 0):

Your table already appears to be summarised by Category, Product and MonthNumber, for SalesQuantity. If so, try this:

```
select distinct Category, Product
from Sales s11_12
where MonthNumber in (11,12) and
      not exists (select null
                  from Sales s10
                  where s10.Category = s11_12.Category and
                        s10.Product = s11_12.Product and
                        s10.SalesQuantity >= s11_12.SalesQuantity)
```